# Why is _POST sometimes empty when a textarea is posted in PHP

Tags: php, apache2

PHP 4.4 and PHP 5.2.3 under Apache 2.2.4 on ubuntu.

I am running Moodle 1.5.3 and have recently had a problem when updating a course. The $_POST variable is empty but only if a lot of text was entered into the textarea on the form. If only a short text is entered it works fine.

I have increased the post_max_size from 8M to 200M and increased the memory_limit to 256M  but this has not helped.
I have doubled the LimitRequestFieldSize and LimitRequestLine to 16380 and set LimitRequestBody to 0 with no improvement.

I have googled for an answer but have been unable to find one.

HTTP Headers on firefox shows the content size of 3816 with the correct data, so its just not getting to $_POST.

The system was running fine until a few weeks ago. The only change was to /etc/hosts to correct a HELO issue with the exim4 email server.

I can replicate the issue on a development machine that has exim4 not running so I think it is just coincidence.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Bizarre. Have you identified the exact threshold? Details could be useful for those wishing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: you said there's no problems with small amounts of text: have you been able to find the approximate limit?

Comment: This may be obvious, but have you checked that the form does indeed use POST, and not GET?

Comment: No, The exact threshold appears to vary but 2702 characters seems to make it fail, sometimes less

Comment: Hmmm... I definitely think you need to keep work on identifying the problem. The fact that it's variable suggests you haven't run into some fixed limit, and it's likely you're running into a bug, possibly related to memory management. Any strange characters? Anything non-standard about the form?

Comment: The text includes html tags. The form has some javascript and hidden fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be not the size related of the post, but how long the line is before a new line. If they use the Moodle WYSIWYG view the html would just get put into one line with no breaks. If you go into html and hit return around every 1000 characters does it work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough to really provide a useful answer so the following is more a well-educated guess (at least I hope so).

First, you should debug the entire request, either by access_log or for example through [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/). (Good to have Firebug anyway.) To me your problem *sounds* like a redirect happens in between. I give you an example:

Assume this is your structure:

```
/form.php
/directory/index.php
```

This is your form:

```
<form action="/directory" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Problem in this case is, that even though `/directory` is a valid url, Apache will redirect you one more time to `/directory/`, thus you are loosing your payload (what is supposed to be in `$_POST`).

Answer (score 1):

What is the enctype of the form? Could be that it limits the ammount of data send through the form.

You might also want to check the incoming raw $_POST data with:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

To make sure their is actually data send.
Got these suggestions [here](http://www.bradino.com/php/empty-post-array/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an Apache or Apache/PHP integration problem. If $_POST is empty it would hint that the http server is not giving the POST information to PHP. If I were you I'd investigate the Apache configuration.

Comment: HTTP Live Headers (a firefox extension) shows the POST content correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious, but did you /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ?

Also, the error_log file should show some information about whether the post size exceeded the set limit. Consider increasing your verbosity for troubleshooting the issue